# React Component State and API fetch

Tags: reactjs

I have been studying React for past few days. In my blog project, I am using Axios to get data from API. Here is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { apiConstants } from "../../constants";
import SinglePost from "./SinglePost";

const PostContent = props => {
  const {
    match: { params }
  } = props;
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(apiConstants.singlePost + `${params.post_slug}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        setPost(response.data);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <SinglePost post={post} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PostContent;
```

Above code works fine though I noticed the first time it tries to render the component with empty ({}) post object (Due to the default value in 'useState'). However, it causes issues in my child component cause it is directly using 'post' object properties. For example: 'post.content'. Here is my 'SinglePost' component's code:

```
const SinglePost = props => {
  const { post } = props;
  console.log(post);
  return (
      <div>{post.content}</div>
  );
};
```

It returns undefined error for {post.content} object. To resolve the issue I had to use something like `{post && <SinglePost post={post} />}`, But it doesn't feel right. Is there any better way to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider revising the `PostContent` component's rendering logic to account for the case where no post data is present during the network request.

You could for instance initialise your `post` state to `null`, and then update the rendered result to prevent the `SinglePost` component from being rendered while `post` is `null`.

Once the network request is completed and the `post` state is set, the component will re-render causing `SinglePost` to be rendered with the non-null `post` state:

```
const PostContent = props => {
  const {
    match: { params }
  } = props;
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null); /* Update: "Initial data" set to null */

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(apiConstants.singlePost + `${params.post_slug}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        setPost(response.data);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    { /* <React.Fragment> Not needed */ }
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            { /* Update: If post is null, assume network request is
                 still in progress so rendering loading message instead
                 of single post component */ }
            { post === null ? <p>Loading</p> : <SinglePost post={post} /> }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
  );
};

export default PostContent;
```

This approach is generally the simplest and more common pattern to async requests and rendering.

There are some other approaches that you might want to consider such as this [declarative approach to data fetching](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-async-for-declarative-data-fetching), or the use of [Reacts suspense feature for asynchronous rendering](https://blog.logrocket.com/async-rendering-in-react-with-suspense-5d0eaac886c8/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is similar to the one I proposed. Of course, 'Loading' message is a plus from UI point of view. However, my main concern is that (considering my lack of experience in React), is it normal to handle such cases or am I approaching it wrong?

Comment: Yes this is quite a common approach solution for these situations. I've just updated my answer with links to some other techniques that you might find interesting to study. Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make post's initial value an array:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { apiConstants } from "../../constants";
import SinglePost from "./SinglePost";

const PostContent = props => {
  const {
    match: { params }
  } = props;
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(apiConstants.singlePost + `${params.post_slug}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        setPost(response.data);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <SinglePost post={post} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PostContent;
```

and in single post map through the array

```
const SinglePost = props => {
  const { post } = props;
  console.log(post);
  return (
    <div>
      {post.map((post, key) => (
        <div key={key}>{post.content}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { apiConstants } from "../../constants";
import SinglePost from "./SinglePost";

const PostContent = props => {
  const {
    match: { params }
  } = props;
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(apiConstants.singlePost + `${params.post_slug}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        setPosts(response.data);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            {this.state.posts.map(post => (<SinglePost post={post} key={post.id} />))

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PostContent;
```